# How do I get JSON from URL and set its value to texfield?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, json

I have some URL mysite.com/json.php, which returns something like this : `[{"invoice_number":"INV#20101"}]`

on another page I have a `<input type="hidden" id="myinvoice" />`

I just wanted to set that `invoice_number` value to this hidden field withJQuery. How can I do this?

on JSON page I have converted JSON with this code :

```
 <?php

$return_arr = array();

$fetch = mysql_query("SELECT invoice_number FROM db_stocks ORDER BY stock_id DESC LIMIT 1 "); 

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($fetch, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {

    $row_array['invoice_number'] = $row['invoice_number'];

    array_push($return_arr,$row_array);
}

echo json_encode($return_arr);

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following jquery:

```
$.get('mysite.com/json.php', function(data){
    $('#myinvoice').val(data[0].invoice_number);
} 'json');
```

Also please don't use mysql but use pdo or mysqli instead, see [why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php) for more information about this.

Comment: His data is an array you have to get the first element

Comment: this Works But i have to chage $.get to $.getJSON

Answer (score 2):

You can use [jQuery.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) to get the returned array then set the value.

```
$.ajax({
  url: "json.php",
  success: function(data) {
    $("#myinvoice").val(data[0].invoice_number);
  }
});
```